# Running gswin64c from an Apache CGI on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, ghostscript

I'm trying to run `gswin64c.exe` from a CGI on Apache for Windows. My program calls `gswin64c.exe` (I can see it in the Task Manager) but it hangs there forever.

My Lazarus (FreePascal) program calls it as this:

```
lProcess.Executable:='C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin64c.exe';
lProcess.Options := [poWaitOnExit];
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-dINITDEBUG');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-dNOSAFER');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-dNOGC');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-dNOPAUSE');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-dBATCH');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-dDisplayResolution=600');
lProcess.Parameters.Add(lPaperSize);
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-sDEVICE=mswinpr2');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-sOutputFile="%printer%' + APrinter + '"');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-sstdout=salida.out');
lProcess.Parameters.Add('-sstderr=salida.err');
lProcess.Parameters.Add(lFile);
```

As you can see, I added the `-dINITDEBUG`, `-sstdout` and `-sstderr` parameters to output some info to an external file. The file `salida.out` is generated with this contents:

```
START 0 1471928 174522 1310688 29492 true 565 3 <0>
GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
END PROCS 1 1520776 223987 1330888 35436 true 671 3 <0>
END FONTDIR/ENCS 2 1549424 257612 1330888 37932 true 681 3 <0>
END DEVS 2 1589024 292939 1330888 37932 true 685 3 <0>
END STATD 3 1609224 310667 1330888 40828 true 690 3 <0>
END GS_FONTS 5 1678272 386498 1330888 40828 true 719 3 <0>
END BASIC COLOR 5 1698472 396103 1330888 40828 true 735 3 <0>
END IMAGE 6 1698472 404147 1330888 40828 true 740 3 <0>
BEGIN RESOURCES 15 2541832 1191647 1436040 146700 true 761 4 <0>
END CATEGORY 15 2541832 1195766 1436040 146996 true 762 5 <0>
END GENERIC 16 2572068 1220038 1436040 146996 true 764 4 <0>
END FIXED 17 2592268 1237641 1436040 146996 true 764 4 <0>
END MISC 17 2592268 1249425 1436040 146996 true 764 4 <0>
END ENCODING 18 2652868 1306819 1436040 150634 true 764 4 <0>
END INITFILES 41 4054488 2645409 1436040 153496 true 982 4 <0>
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin/Fontmap 42 4054488 2650897 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\lib/Fontmap 43 4115088 2687451 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\fonts/Fontmap 43 4115088 2698191 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
%rom%Resource/Init/Fontmap 44 4135288 2712349 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
%rom%lib/Fontmap 45 4155488 2730865 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
c:/gs/gs9.27/Resource/Init/Fontmap 46 4175688 2745031 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
c:/gs/gs9.27/lib/Fontmap 46 4175688 2755755 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
c:/gs/gs9.27/Resource/Font/Fontmap 47 4195888 2769921 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
c:/gs/fonts/Fontmap 47 4216088 2784072 1456240 158774 true 983 4 <1>
END FONTS 48 4216088 2794885 1456240 158774 true 982 4 <0>
```

But nothing else.

BTW, I created a command line program using exactly the same parameters and it works as expected.

Does anyone have faced a similar issue using `gswin64c` from an Apache2 CGI on Windows?.

Note: before asking here I created a long thread on the Lazarus forums, please see: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,51727.0.html

Answer (score 0):

I am current facing this same problem.  I am trying to use gswin64c to send PDFs to the printer from PHP on an Apache server.  It works fine as long as I'm running Apache using my own user account, but if Apache is running as a service (in Windows, using the SYSTEM account), it no longer functions.  Hangs forever.

If you run gswin64c through "psexec -sid" as seen here (https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-program-as-system-localsystem-account-windows/), you will see that when running as the SYSTEM account the printer is not being selected.  On my system at least the SYSTEM account can see the printer.  I don't know yet why it's refusing to select it.

I ended up solving this problem in my scenario by dropping gswin64c.exe altogether and writing a small C#/.NET Core program that can send a PDF file from the command-line arguments to the printer, using the example detailed here: https://www.dynamicpdf.com/examples/print-pdf-.net-core?filter=print&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuL_8BRCXARIsAGiC51D8XVS2WxFWgoLir5Mg4W3A22NIEQtFlUSkJqTsCDnfsGfUpQy_7mwaAoTyEALw_wcB